# How to implement not full screen file preview on ios

Tags: ios, file, preview, qlpreviewcontroller

I know QLPreviewController could do this. But it's full screen, my requirement is preview files in a subview.

I tried use a offline window to present the QLPreviewController, and then make a screenshot of the offline window.

The problem is i have to show the window, otherwise the screen shot doesn't catch any thing.

Then my question could be, how to make screen shot for offline window in ios ?

Or you may have better ideas of implement file preview in another way.

Any tips will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

QLPreviewController can be in a subview.

I self use it in a spliview and a subclassed QLPreviewController.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    DocumentViewController *documentViewController = [DocumentViewController new];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:documentViewController animated:YES];
    [documentViewController release];
}
```

where DocumentViewController is a subclass of QLPreviewController:

```
@interface DocumentViewController : QLPreviewController <QLPreviewControllerDataSource>

@implementation DocumentViewController

...
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) 
    {
        self.dataSource = self;
        self.delegate = self;
    }
    return self;
}
...
```

and implement the methods witch you want (numberOfPreviewItemsInPreviewController is required for the datasource)